# How to load ng-repeat when switching with routes?

Tags: angularjs

I want to load the data from the api when i click the route instead of the button i have atm.

i tried calling the function with ng-click on the index.html but it didnt work.

routes:

```
import { app } from "../index";

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    $routeProvider
        .when("/drivers", {
            templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/drivers.html",
        })
        .when("/teams", {
            templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/teams.html",
        })
        .when("/races", {
            templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/races.html",
        });
});
```

app controller:

```
 import {app} from '../index';

 app.controller("api", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.Naziv = "Driver Championship Standings - 2013";
$scope.TopDrivers = function () {
    console.log("i been pressed");
    $http.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json")
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.drivers = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
            console.log("response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists.0.DriverStandings");
            console.log(response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Unable to perform get request");
        });
}
 });
```

my ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller="api">
    <p>{{Naziv}}</p>
    <button ng-click="TopDrivers()">Test Rest</button>
    <div ng-repeat="x in drivers | orderBy: '+Points'">
        <div id="divRow">
            <table>
                <tr id="tableRow">
                  <td id="td1">Nb: {{x.position}}</td>
                  <td id="td2">
                    {{x.Constructors[0].nationality}} {{x.Driver.givenName}} {{x.Driver.familyName}}
                  </td>
                  <td id="td3">{{x.Constructors[0].name}}</td>
                  <td id="td4">Points{{x.points}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html how the route is called

```
 <p class="leftText" id="firstPLEft">
   <img class="leftPictures" src="img/drivers.png" alt="DriversPng">
   <a href="#!drivers">Drivers</a>
 </p>
```

i want to load the api and have it give me the ng-repeat results when i switch to the route instead of when i click the button in the route.[image: how it currently works]

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you can also use route.resolve({PROMISE}) to make the data available on route change.

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer Marko, Please check another approach as well. You can pick anyone depending on your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `ng-init`

```
<div ng-controller="api" ng-init="TopDrivers()">
    <p>{{Naziv}}</p>
    <buttonTest Rest</button>
    <div ng-repeat="x in drivers | orderBy: '+Points'">
        <div id="divRow">
            <table>
                <tr id="tableRow">
                  <td id="td1">Nb: {{x.position}}</td>
                  <td id="td2">
                    {{x.Constructors[0].nationality}} {{x.Driver.givenName}} {{x.Driver.familyName}}
                  </td>
                  <td id="td3">{{x.Constructors[0].name}}</td>
                  <td id="td4">Points{{x.points}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Or, you can use `resolve` in `$routeProvider`:

```
app.factory("someService", function($http){
    return {
        getData: function(){
            return $http.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json");
        }
    };
});
```

and in config:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/drivers", {
        templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/drivers.html",
        controller: "api",
        resolve: {
        message: function(someService){
            return messageService.getData();
    }
    })
    .when("/teams", {
        templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/teams.html",
    })
    .when("/races", {
        templateUrl: "./src/pageDetails/races.html",
    });
```

[A sample demo on how to use it](http://embed.plnkr.co/wKnZw5wmk1kle8FSy4FL/)